# TFS 2010: Email Notification List for Work Items?

Tags: email, team-foundation-server

Our previous work item tracking system had a feature called "notification list". In addition to the individual who is assigned a work item, any user included in this list would also receive an email when the work item was updated. This made it very easy to keep apprised of changes to specific work items. Especially for those of us who work out of our inboxes.

Is there any way to set something up in TFS that works in a similar fashion?

Note: Our TFS guru did set up a similar mechanism, but whoever updates a work item must specify the list of users to be notified *every time they update a work item*. That unfortunately is not a very effective solution. We're hoping to be able to define a global list of recipients once (or update it as needed) and have updates automatically emailed to users on that list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution on CodePlex will meet our requirements. It works with TFS 2008, but we have contacted the developer and he is creating a build for 2010.

http://tfswiwatcher.codeplex.com/

Comment: In fact, the developer just put up a TFS 2010 build about an hour ago :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [TFS PowerTools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f/) to install the Alerts Explorer which enables you to create alert profiles to send emails when work items have changed according to critera that you define.

Comment: We presently use the Alerts Explorer but it is very limited when it comes to custom fields - see the final paragraph in the original post. That is the present solution we are using with Alerts Explorer and does not really meet our requirements.